# how do make an Archimedean spiral of words decreasing in font size every 3 characters?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am attempting to do a logo where the phrase starts at the top of a spiral and continues throughout the spiral decreasing in size until the very middle of the spiral.

Tried the Spiral tool but not close enough and manually decreased font every three characters but the spiral did not continue to the very middle.  I think i need to use an Archimedean spiral?

Answer (score 2):

While making Spiral Pres <kbd>CTR Key</kbd> for making change in distance of segments and also pres <kbd>UP arrow</kbd>and<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> key to icrease and decrease number of segments. Also just click on Artboard after selecting spiral tool for all spiral options like decay and number of segments.

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution

1. type your phrase with your desire font and convert this phrase to outline type>create outline
2. drag the result into your brush panel as an art brush
3. draw your spiral shape and apply this brush to it. and you may need to adjust the brush in the stroke option panel to proportional. as show in the next dialouge box.

[image]

4. adjust the thickness of the result by using the **width tool** [shift+w] and make it wider from the beginning and narrow from the end. as show in the next screen capture. this will ensure full control over the thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After playing around with Illustrator I might have a solution for ya. The real question is do you need to have the text live for edits in the future. If so This will not work for you. What I did was take a long string of text. And then converted the text to Outlines. Then used the Transform Tool to Distort the text Larger on the Left and smaller on the right. Then to create the spiral I created a New Art Brush out of the outlined text (Left the default settings). From here I used the spiral tool to create a spiral that has no stroke or fill and applied the New Art Brush that was created from the Outlined text.